# UBUNTU 9.10: using arrow keys for navigating tasks in task switching window

Tags: windows, ubuntu, keyboard-shortcuts

Is it possible to use arrow keys for navigating tasks in task switching window (which opens when you press Alt+Tab) as it's possible in windows 7.

It will help to quickly navigate to next row of tasks (when you've many tasks open), rather than pressing alt-tab repeatedly.

Comment: You can consider using Scale (a Compiz plug-in). http://polishlinux.org/reviews/mandriva_2007_free_xgl/scale.png

Comment: Thanks for the response, but for some odd reason I just don't want to enable Compiz on my laptop. My ATI drivers cause the X to hang if they are enabled. :(

Comment: Thanks chopeen. I've updated the ATI drivers and am able to use scale. It's a nice plug-in and does what I required.

P.S. Can you move your comment to an answer so I can mark it as resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Ubuntu 9.10 I have something called "Window Picker" (which may or may not be Chopeen's Scale), initiated with Alt-Shift-Up.  Hit those Keys and then hold the Alt & Shift down while using the arrows keys to move between windows.

In case I've changed the keyboard shortcut to initiate it, use the System > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts app to see what it's bound to on your system (it's under Desktop).